# Adding a whole number and a decimal in Javascript results in removal of the decimal?

Tags: javascript, numbers, double, rounding

I'm sure this is simple, but in my javascript code, I have two numbers. One contains a decimal, and the other doesn't, and I add them together (ie. 7.5 + 5), I am getting a result with NO decimal value.

Do I need to cast each number variable as a double? I know that all numbers are doubles in javascript - which is why I do not understand this behavior...

For instance, I have `var answer = week1 + week2;`. Does this make sense?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. Can you add a [mcve]?

Comment: Can't possibly tell what the problem is without any code.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for wasting time - turns out I was using parseInt instead of parseFloat to gather the "week" values I spoke about.

Can someone please close this question or delete it? Before the shame consumes me?